# Java - Error initialising Object Array List

Tags: java

I am getting a null pointer exception when I try to use the perimeter function in my code. It seems that the Points array (Point is a simple object with an x and y coordinate) is not correctly initialising, I believe I may have declared the array wrongly or the constructor is incorrect.

```
package shapes;

import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Triangle {

private int sides = 3;
private Point[] Points = new Point[sides];

public Triangle(Point[] vertices) {
    vertices = Points;
}

public double perimeter() {
    return Points[0].distance(Points[1]) + Points[1].distance(Points[2]) + Points[2].distance(Points[0]);
}

public double area() {
    double semiperimeter = perimeter() / 2;
    return sqrt(semiperimeter * (semiperimeter - Points[0].distance(Points[1])) * (semiperimeter - Points[1].distance(Points[2])) * (semiperimeter - Points[2].distance(Points[0])));
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Triangle has perimeter of " + perimeter() + " and an area of " + area(); 
}

public void translate(int dx, int dy) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Points[i].translate(dx, dy);
    }
}

public void scale(int factor) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Points[i].scale(factor);
    }        
}

public Point getVertex(int i) {
    return Points[i];
}

}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're initializing the array. Are you initializing its elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reverse this in your constructor:

```
vertices = Points;
```

to

```
Points = vertices ;
```

You need to initialize your `Points` array with the input `vertices` and not the other way around.

Comment: So simple, you got it! Thanks haha

Comment: @h1h1 it happens..just accept the answer if it helped!